# Ruby 2d array of hashes with runtime-decided length

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, objectid

I am trying to do something like this in a ruby module:

```
def initialize
  super
  @@main_array = Array.new(16) { Array.new} 
end

def add_hash(hash={})
  @@main_array[get_id] << hash
end
# Where get_id returns 0-15
```

I expect each sub-array to have only the hashes that were added to it. Instead, all sub-arrays have all hashes added. Inspecting the array shows that the sub-arrays all share object ID's.

I'm not sure why this is the case. What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

Here's the exact code I'm using:

```
module Manager
  def initialize
    super
    @@main_array = Array.new(BaseCompany.get_number_thread(), Array.new())
  end

  def self.check_and_add_thread_activity(activity={})
    action = Hash.new
    action[:id] = @@main_array[BaseCompany.get_current_threadid].length +1 
    action[:name] = activity[:name]
    action[:added] = true
    @@main_array[BaseCompany.get_current_threadid] << action
    return action
  end

end
```

Check_and_add is called by other parts of the code, as the individual threads execute functionality

Okay, I've actually solved it. In the comments below someone mentioned that this:

```
Array.new(16,Array.new)
```

Would cause the sub-arrays to have the same object ID. Someone else corrected him saying it shouldn't happen, but this was the case in my code. I replaced that line with the recommended:

```
Array.new(16) {Array.new}
```

And this worked just fine.

For reference, I'm using JRuby 1.7.3

Comment: Can you show test code using this?

Comment: What do you mean by testcode?

Comment: Code that is using `initialize` and `add_hash`. I have tried this in irb and it works as expected. Are you sure you didn't type this somewhere? `@@main_array = Array.new(16, Array.new)`. That would create 16 arrays with same object_id.

Comment: They shouldn't if he used that code in initialize.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš oh, indeed, my mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, not in the piece of code you've demonstrated. I suppose the problem is somewhere where you populate your Array

Comment: Problem may be because `@@main_array` is class variable instead of instance variable. Impossible to tell without the code using his code.

Comment: I've edited to include more code. Please let me know if you need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Array.new(size, object)

```
main_array = Array.new(16, Array.new)
```

is equivalent to :

```
row = Array.new
main_array = Array.new(16,row)
```

or just

```
main_array = [row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row]
```

So you have 16 times exactly the same object (one empty Array). Modifying one element will automatically modifiy all the others :

```
p main_array
#=> [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

row << 1

p main_array
#=> [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

## Array.new(size){ }

```
main_array = Array.new(16){ Array.new }
```

is equivalent to :

```
main_array = (1..16).map{ Array.new }
```

or :

```
main_array = [Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new, Array.new]
```

Now you have 16 empty Arrays, but they are all different objects. Modifying one element won't modify any of the other arrays :

```
main_array = Array.new(16){ Array.new }

p main_array
#=> [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

main_array[0] << 1

p main_array
#=> [[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```